# How to install XAMPP without MariaDB?

Tags: xampp, mariadb, mysql-python

How can I install XAMPP with MySQLdb (old version) instead of MariaDB in windows 10 ?

Comment: Find an older release of XAMPP?

Comment: is there any method to downgrade or similar way ?

Comment: I know that WAMP lets you install multiple versions; I don't know about XAMPP.  An old version can be installed on Win10; the question is whether XAMPP makes it easy.